# in jmeter, the value of dynamic variable gets parsed in json ( "${var}"), but still server throws 400-bad request error

Tags: json, jmeter

header:
Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8
Accept:application/json

In json POST request, i substituted the id as "identifier":"${var}". i have extracted the var using regex as "identifier":"(.+?)" template: $1$ match no:1
This id gets used 8 times in my request-1 time as an identifier & 7 times as [
:   :   :   {
:   :   :   :   "id":123,
:   :   :   :   "reportId":"${var}" //7times,
:   :   :   :   "team":"100"
:   :   :   },

i checked the request & it seems to be correct. not understanding why there's an error if the value gets parsed (checked in debug sampler).
If i pass static value, the test passes.

**error:**Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2018-02-15 10:03:37 IST
Load time: 441
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 310
Size in bytes: 12297
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 552
Body size in bytes: 11745
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 400
Response message: Bad Request

Comment: Show the response you try to get var from

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. i solved it. there was an extra '\' n json body

Answer (score 0):

1. Double check your `${var}` variable value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) combination
2. Make sure to add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type)
3. Double you're sending syntactically correct JSON payload using i.e. [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) tool

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. i solved it. there was an extra '\' n json body